# d3 __data__ and protractor E2E testing

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, protractor

I have the scoured the internet to get an answer for this but couldn't find one.

How can you get the **data** attached to an element from a protractor test?

element(by.css('path')) returns an object with a few methods such as getText(), count() etc but there is no way I can get the **data** attached to the path.

I need this to get the depth of the path and then click on a correct path with desired depth.

I can of course attached an attribute to the `<path>` e.g. `<path data-depth=3>` but I don't want to add an attribute just so I can write E2E tests

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you make the problem more specific - provide the HTML code and the desired element/data you want to locate? Thanks.

Comment: If anyone is looking for solution for a similar problem see fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/hsuh/euom9fpa/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a script in the browser and get the data from it:

```
browser.executeScript("return d3.select(your_element).data()").then(function(data) {
  // work with data
});
```

Comment: The problem is that how do I get that data back to protractor?

`var depth;
 browser.executeScript(
"return d3.select(your_element).data()").then(function(data) {
  depth = data.depth;
});

console.log('depth', depth); //depth is undefined.`

Comment: You get it back to protractor via a promise, like almost everything. It's the same behavior when you do `elem.getText()`, you cannot console.log that directly. WHat you can do is write the console.log and the rest of the step inside the `.then()` callback

Comment: So, what I need is to do a map on the data in the then() block and get a path and click on that path.

`then(function(path){
     path.click();
`
How can I click on that element? Normal click() won't work because it is not a protractor element. It's a html element. 

Path will look like this - <path d="M-306.9,-155.3681,343.990 0,1 -6.31904e-14,-343.993L-3.73e-14,-203.0630203.08,203.063 0 0,0 -181.17,-91.71547Z" style="opacity: 1; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></path>

Many thanks.

Comment: How do you map this path to the data? Sorry I am not sure what you mean, and it is a different question. In worst case, you can do all the code from the browser, including the click with vanilla or jQuery, in your `browser.executeScript`.

Comment: Sorry I'm not being clear. I've created a fiddle here to show you what I mean - https://jsfiddle.net/euom9fpa/1/

1. path is not returned even though in the browser.execute block path is available and returned
2. how do I click the path() element. I can create a different stackoverflow post for this though.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed a browser.sleep() before clicking on the path. https://jsfiddle.net/hsuh/euom9fpa/4/
Thanks for your help. :)